# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline set location of static files

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible to deploy static files to /wwwroot?

I have tried web deploy and zip deploy, and the closest I can get is via Web Deploy it will deploy the files to /wwwroot/a

but I cannot figure out how to deploy static files directly to /wwwroot

Comment: Are you sure that your zip file doesn't have inside folder `a`?

Comment: i dont have any folders named /a. well maybe one is created during the build pipeline?

Comment: It could be. Please download your artifact to local machine and check it manually.

Comment: ah there is an /a direction inside of the zipped directory!!  i will accept your answer if you want to leave something of that sorts.  but i guess now i do have a follow up question.  i guess the archive step in my build pipeline is creating an /a directory, and is it possible to prevent that from happening.  i do not have an /a directory in my source files.  thanks!

Comment: oh wow i think i found it..  the pipeline directory is /a. and there is an option on the archive step:  Prepend root folder name to archive paths
that was checked!!  I'm thinking that will fix it.  if you want to leave an answer i will accept. thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited my original answer with this founding. I'm glad that we found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you don't you have `a` folder zipping your files.

For instance `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` is

> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a

So it could that your grabbed also `a` folder form this.

Comment: i guess i'm confused maybe but my question had to do with file path not creds?

Comment: No, i understood that. But you have different type of credentials and kudu needs separate. Above script put file in `scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/YourFile.txt` so my mistake is that I give you solution to put single file (it can be changed to upload while folder), not the credential's

Comment: i'm not trying to do this thru kudu.  i can access kudu already.  and i can see that the files are in wwwroot/a i don't know why the pipeline is putting them in wwwroot/a though.  I want them to be placed in wwwroot

Comment: i'm in the pipeline, and using app service deploy.  I've tried zip option and web deploy option.  but it seems to pick location wwwroot/a

Comment: also i would hope not to use powershell.  i would like to use standard release pipeline tasks